# Load Impedance Derivation

Tags: rf, transmission-line

I'm having some trouble deriving this equation for transmission line theory:

[image]

From: http://www.antenna-theory.com/tutorial/txline/transmission3.php

When I sub the Telegrapher's equations into eqn marked 1 in image, I can't seem to get rid of the exponentials. See my attempt:

[image]

Comment: Just choose the coordinate system where z=0 at the location of the load.

Comment: Oh wow. That fixes it. But wouldn't I get I^+ + I^- on the bottom rather than with a negative sign between like in the derivation?

Comment: I think there is an error in the equations posted. The current at a point is sum of the forward and backward going current. Hence I(z,t) = I_fwd - I_back NOT  I_fwd + I_back

Comment: But the voltage is a sum though?

Comment: If you set z=0, you get rid of the z-terms (see @The Photon's comment). All that is left are 2x top and 2x bottom equal terms of exp(jwt) which can be canceled out right away. And yes: The sign is wrong in the equations posted!